# Could you please help me figure out the bugs in my code?

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    name=None
    sex=None
    def __init__(self,name,sex):
        self.name=name
        self.sex=sex
        print("构造函数的调用")
    def name(self):
        print(self.name)
    def sex(self):
        print(self.sex)
a=input()
b=input()
p=Person(a,b)
p.name()
p.sex()
```

This is my codes in Python.I'm a green hand.Please help me. THANKS

The compiler told me I could not use the string class.I don't understand why I could not use that

Comment: please share the full error log.

Comment: `p.name` is a string but the syntax `p.name()` is trying to treat that string as a function.

Comment: if you rename self.name to self._name you will see that that will fix it, you cannot use the same name for methods and variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here you're defining two class members `name` and `sex`:

```
def __init__(self,name,sex):
    self.name=name
    self.sex=sex
```

And here you're **also** defining two class members `name` and `sex`:

```
def name(self):
    print(self.name)
def sex(self):
    print(self.sex)
```

You can't have class members with the same names.

When you call `__init__()`, the *methods* are overwritten by the *strings* of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You set variable name as same as your function name,the compiler thinks

```
p.name()
```

is use the variable you define.
To fix the error,you can change the function name or variable name,Like this

```
class Person:
  name=None
  sex=None
  def __init__(self,name,sex):
      self.name=name
      self.sex=sex
      print("构造函数的调用")
  def print_name(self):
      print(self.name)
  def print_sex(self):
      print(self.sex)
a=input()
b=input()
p=Person(a,b)
p.print_name()
p.print_sex()
```

Hope this can help you :)